# How to validate a date in shell script

Tags: bash, validation, date

I am relatively new to shell scripting. It would be really helpful if you guys could give me some suggestion about how to validate a date in a shell script.

I have a configuration file in which some dates will be inserted in "yyyy/mm/dd" format. I need to validate this. Please help me.

Comment: Use `date -d"yyyy/mm/dd"` and see if it outputs a date.

Answer (score 0):

```
date -d "16/03/2014 13:111111111100:00"
```

try this

Comment: Yes :) but notice the OP indicates a `YYYY/MM/DD` format and you are giving `DD/MM/YYYY`.

Comment: Thank you sir ..i will notice your advice .But how about @Mr.Mariners,who post this problem :) ...we don't get any response